# How can I color a particular part of a view, as if you were using the fill tool gimp or paint?

Tags: objective-c

How can I color a particular part of a view, as if you were using the fill tool gimp or paint? Let me explain. If I have to color a square divided in half by a black line, how do I select the part E 'DELIMITED BY BLACKS EDGES? I know how to catch and paint a part, but if I want to paint just a portion enclosed by the edges of a different color?

Comment: If you create the dividing line, save its location and build a path that you can fill.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a floodfill, and the standard OSX and iOS APIs dont have it. It's not something you would do unless you are writing a graphics editor yourself. Ordinary filled graphics are created using for example NSPath to define the edges of the shape, then giving a fill color as well as potentially a stroke (line) color.

If you ARE writing a graphics editor, or have another unusual case where you do need a floodfill, there are people who've written them for Cocoa already. Google for "Cocoa floodfill". I won't link to one here as I haven't tried them, and anyway the best for you might vary depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: ok thanks. I thought you could do something similar by analyzing the pixels do not know. For logic at this point I think to make sure that you are looking for the part that wants to color and that's it =)